# Can I ask for module recommendations here?

Tags: discussion

For example, I wish to write some software, but don't know what libraries/modules I should use. May I ask a question like that here?

Comment: Would this be OT for SO? Have you seen this [question](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/8/is-it-alright-to-ask-for-programming-tools) which covers the same question more broadly?